# how to use getpixel() after zooming a bitmap in android

Tags: android

I am using a bitmap image,initially i can easily get the pixels colors by using getpixel() method of Bitmap class.but when i zoom this image in ondraw() method of canvas then how will i use getpixel() method. I am not getting zoomed bitmap object?

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: cant understnd pls paste ur relevant code with detailed description

Answer (score 1):

Stunningly vague question, but ASSUMING you are "zooming" by using `Matrix.setScale()` or `postScale()` in a custom View's `onDraw()`, then whatever your scaling factor is for that simply divide your pixel coords by that when calling `Bitmap.getPixel()`.